# In the Sex and the City series, were there any actor allusions to Square Pegs?

Tags: reference, sex-and-the-city-tv, square-pegs

During the entire run of "Sex and the City" (including the film follow-ups), were there any references/call backs (referred to as the trope "actor allusion") to lead actress Sarah Jessica Parker's earlier role as Patty Greene on "Square Pegs"?

If so, cite the episode(s) and supporting text.

Comment: Tracy Nelson (Jennifer DiNuccio) had a guest appearance on an episode of *Still Standing*, starring Jami Gertz (Muffy Temperman) 20 years after *Square Pegs*. Sorry, that's the closest I've got.